# wlanapi - will WlanFreeMemory free its WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO array struct?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wlanapi

I am using Microsoft's WLAN API in the following code (I left only the relevant pieces from the example):

[`WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706873.aspx)

[`WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706868.aspx)

[`WlanEnumInterfaces()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706716.aspx)

[`WlanFreeMemory()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706722.aspx)

```
PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pIfList = NULL;
WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO pIfInfo = NULL;
WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, NULL, &pIfList); 
pIfInfo = pIntfList->InterfaceInfo[i];
WlanFreeMemory(pIfList);
```

I am saving the active interface, which is located in `pIntfList->InterfaceInfo[i]`,  to `pIfInfo`.

Will `WlanFreeMemory(pIfList)` also free `pIfInfo` and leave this variable useless? Or is its values copied to a new structure when doing `pIfInfo = pIntfList->InterfaceInfo[i]`?

Is there any way to avoid keeping the entire `WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO` struct variable and only keeping a `PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will `WlanFreeMemory(pIfList)` also free `pIfInfo` and leave this variable useless?

No. Your variable `pIfInfo` is actually a struct rather than a pointer. So when you write

```
WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO pIfInfo = NULL;
WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, NULL, &pIfList); 
pIfInfo = pIntfList->InterfaceInfo[i];
```

you are taking a copy of the struct. Note that the code does not compile because you cannot assign `NULL` to a struct. Note also that `pIfInfo` is a poor choice of name because it implies to the read that the variable is a pointer.

Now, the call to `WlanFreeMemory(pIfList)` will free all of the memory allocated, including the array `pIntfList->InterfaceInfo[]`. But since you take a copy of the struct, a copy of element `i` of the array, that does not affect you.

I would probably write your code like this:

```
PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pIfList;
if (WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, NULL, &pIfList) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // handle error
}
WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO IfInfo = pIntfList->InterfaceInfo[i];
WlanFreeMemory(pIfList);
// can still use IfInfo, but not pIfList
```

Comment: Thanks! the code problems are caused by some rushed copy and paste i did from Microsoft example and my own code. But isn't it possible that `WlanFreeMemory(pIfList);` will recursivly free the `WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO` array inside `pIntfList`, which will also free `IfInfo ` ?

Comment: It will free that array, but you took a **copy** of the struct